# Need help reading Parse Geopoint JSON

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

Before this question is deemed repeated, let me clarify that I'm a complete newbie and have spend more than 4 hours trying to google the answer. But I haven't found it yet.

I have a set of geopoints in Parse backend like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUBKm.png)

I'm storing this in local varibale locationList. I tried 2 ways of reading the lat long:

```
var lat = locationList[0].geolocation.latitude;
```

AND

```
var locations = JSON.parse(locationList);
var lat = locations[0].geolocation.latitude;
```

Both ways are giving me errors. In the first method geolocation is showing up as undefined. In the second I get this:
http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/7080/lgte0c5.png

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the surrounding code context.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a LONG time to figure out, but

```
 object.attributes.geolocation.longitude
```

works for me. Hope that helps!